# Loading arrays dynamically into a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay guys,

I need some help with this jQuery dilemma:

I have 3 arrays declared globally in the header of my website:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
var array3 = [];
```

I have a function like this:

```
function setDropDownList(raw_id){
    jQuery.each(mytest, function(key, value) {
      var mytest = value.split('|');
    }
}
```

Instead of "mytest" I need to dynamically load each of the 3 arrays declared globally above.

How can I do it?

I'm thinking of something lime this:

```
function setDropDownList(raw_id, "??? how can I generate which array I need: array1 or 2 or 3?"){
    jQuery.each(the_needed_array, function(key, value) {
      var the_needed_array = value.split('|');
    }
}
```

In PHP, there is something called **variable variables**, and I could have something like this.

```
var array_name = 'array1';
```

And in the function:

```
$$array_name;
```

Comment: Do you want to run all of them, one after the other? Or are there specific cases for running each array?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the arrays inside the each method, or do you simply need to iterate over them?

Comment: I need to modify them using split and then append some stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing those are global variables, you need to operate on the window object, using the *array notation*
if you have

```
var arrname = 'array1'
window[arrname] = [1,2,3]; // window.arrname won't work but this will
```

then

```
console.log(window.array1)
```

will yield

```
[1,2,3]
```

if they are not global variables you can use *this* instead of window to target whatever is the container object (*this* will actually reference *window* if you're in the global scope).

```
var myobj = {
  myfunc : function() {
    var an = 'iamanarray';
    this[an] = [1,2,3];
    console.log(this[an]);            // [1,2,3]
    console.log(this.an);             // undefined
    console.log(this['iamanarray']);  // [1,2,3]
    console.log(myobj.iamanarray);    // [1,2,3]
    console.log(iamanarray);          // reference error
    console.log(window.iamanarray);   // reference error
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty, calling window[arrname] = [1,2,3]; from inside the function does not work